# How to decrypt the transaction payload when confidentiality is turned on?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

The transactions/<transaction_id> API returns a single transaction. But when confidentiality is turned on, the transaction payload is encrypted

How can I decrypt this transaction payload when confidentiality is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to do so if you have the key pair of who sent the transaction (that's why it is confidential).

If you are the user that sent the transaction then you can retrieve the ECert and TCert using [this](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#registrar). With the certificate you can decrypt the transaction's payload.