# Retrieving full list of transactions for hyperledger

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger

may I ask if there is a way to retrieve all the transactions I have in my blockchain?

For instance, "A" transferred 10 to "B" (first transaction), "B" transferred 10 to "A" (second transaction), so on and so forth.

Thus, is there a way to retrieve the list of transactions and display it?

Comment: Don't know if this is supported out of the box, but you could always just keep a table of all transactions in your chaincode, and just use a query call to return the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all of them, you can iterate over all the blocks in the blockchain using the [REST endpoint](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#block). This will give you all the block's information, including all the transactions in the block.

You can get the whole height (length) of the blockchain using the [GET /chain endpoint](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API/CoreAPI/#block).

Comment: Is this possible when confidentiality is turned on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143344/how-to-decrypt-the-trasaction-payload-when-confidentiality-is-turned-on

Comment: Can u do this using hfc package?