# extracting Payload when confidentiality/security are on

Tags: hyperledger

I have started a network of 4 VPs and 1 CA .

I have setup the privacy/security to be true.

[image: setting privacy and security]

I have successfully Enrolled a user "Lukas"

[image: Enrolling Lukas.]

I have successfully executed a deploy and invoke transaction.

I verified that the transaction exists on the blockchain:
[image: Verifying transaction]

In this Post, [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143344/how-to-decrypt-the-trasaction-payload-when-confidentiality-is-turned-on), it this mentioned that we need either Ecert/Tcert for the transactor ("lukas" in my example) to be able to decrypt the payload.

[image: previous post answer]

I understand that we can get an Ecert/Tcert but calling :

GET /registrar/{enrollmentID}/ecert

GET /registrar/{enrollmentID}/tcert

Can someone please explain how to use these certificates to decrypt the payload ? what command/tool to use?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know privacy/confidentiality is not implemented in Fabric as of version 0.6. The payload you are looking at is not encrypted, but just base64 encoded. You can decode it without any cert. Use https://www.base64decode.org/ to decode base64 encoded text